# enable a function depending on window width and window resize

Tags: jquery, css, width, listener, window-resize

I have a function that I want to enable depending on my window width, to customize my menu for mobile and ipad windows... it works fine, but when I resize my window the function is not triggred again.
let me explain, here is my function Code :

```
if ($(window).width() < 960) {
    $('.button_menu').css("display", "block");
   $('#bloc_menu').hide();
    $('.button_menu').click(function() {     
          $(this).next().slideToggle();
          return false;
    });

}

else {

    $('#bloc_menu').css("display", "block");
    $('.button_menu').css("display", "none");
}
```

if the window width is less than 960, then my menu is hidden, ad I have a button appearing, when clicking on the button, the menu appears.

and if my window is larger than 960, then the button is hidden, and my menu is displayed.

I have also some css rules :

```
#menu{list-style: none;}
.button_menu{display: none}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
#bloc_menu{margin-top: 10px;position: relative;border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;}
```

I just want to add a window resize listener but I can't find the solution to do it, can anybody help me with this ?

thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: `$(window).resize(function(){ .... })`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid it hiding after you have opened it use a flag and toggle it when you click on the button:

```
  var flag = 0;

  $('.button_menu').click(function() {     
          $(this).next().slideToggle();
          if(flag==0){ 
          flag=1;
          } else {
          flag=0;
          }
          return false;
    });

  $( window ).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
    $('.button_menu').css("display", "block");
    if(flag==0){
    $('#bloc_menu').hide();
    }
  }else{
    $('#bloc_menu').css("display", "block");
    $('.button_menu').css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I tried your code and it's not working... here is ajsfiddle to see it in action, the button image is not shown because I'm working in local : http://jsfiddle.net/R46rN/
thanks again for your help

Comment: thanks, I added '.off' in $('.button_menu').off().click(function(), and it works perfectly, thanks a lot, http://jsfiddle.net/R46rN/4/

Comment: You are welcome, I'd suggest you move the click function out of the resize function http://jsfiddle.net/R46rN/5/ - it should'nt really be in there. I updated the code above also.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use jquery's resize function:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {


your code...
});
```

This will trigger your code evertime the window is resized.

Comment: thanks @RMSTOKES, Ok it works, I've found the solution, but when adding the resize(function), when clicking on my button, my menu shows and hide like 3 or 4 times before displaying correctly... do you know why ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$( window ).resize(function() {

    if($(window).width() < 960) {
        $('.button_menu').css("display", "block");
        $('#bloc_menu').hide();
        $('.button_menu').off().click(function() {     
              $(this).next().slideToggle();
              return false;
        });
    }else{
        $('#bloc_menu').css("display", "block");
        $('.button_menu').css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

The resize function can be called multiple times, so it can add many click event listeners to your button. Once you click it would run all of them.

Place the `off()` function right before adding the event listener.

Comment: thanks @ordepim, it works fine, one more question, is it possible to keep the #bloc_menu oppened when resizing ? I mean when my window is less than 960 and I click on the .button_menu, mt #bloc_menu appears, but if I resize then, it disappears... do you see whant I mean ? thanks

Comment: Yes... try this: $( window ).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() < 960) {
        $('.button_menu').css("display", "block");
        if(!$('#bloc_menu').hasClass("onMobile"))$('#bloc_menu').hide();
        $('.button_menu').off().click(function() {     
              $(this).next().slideToggle().addClass("onMobile");
              return false;
        });
    }else{
        $('#bloc_menu').css("display", "block").removeClass("onMobile");
        $('.button_menu').css("display", "none");
    }
});